# Core-Plot Tutorials for Mac

Tags: macos, core-plot

I was wondering if there were any core-plot tutorials available for the Mac.  It looks like all of the tutorials are for iOS, and some of the code is very different.

I'm just trying to create a simple graph with x, y coordinates that I have stored in an array.

Comment: Other than the hosting view (`NSView` vs. `UIView`) and the Mac version supporting bindings in addition to the datasource, the graph code should be identical on either platform.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was the only difference.